# Refining the parsed json data

Tags: java, json

A part of the JSON I recieved is like this - `"Value":["14.1\""]` .
On using the command - `String something = String.valueOf(o.get("Value"));` I'm able to extract whatever's in the value field which comes along with the square brackets, double quotes and the back slash in between. How do I retrieve the data without those square brackets, back slash and double quotes?

Comment: You should have to use `String#replace` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your json is in good format? The Value is a JsonArray

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
JSONArray valueArr = object.getJSONArray("Value");
String result =String.valueOf(valueArr.get(0));
//you'll get :  14.1"

result = result.replace("\"","")
// final: 14.1
```